# Where is using null BSTR documented?

Tags: windows, com, interop, com-interop, bstr

It's at least common practice to treat null BSTR (null WCHAR* pointer) as an empty string and design all the code manipulating BSTRs accordingly. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171641/should-there-be-a-difference-between-an-empty-bstr-and-a-null-bstr) say the same.

Where is this practice documented? Is there any official document describing this convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the link given in the accepted answer to that question is to an article by Eric Lippert, [Eric's Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx).  While it would most definitely *not* be official documentation, Lippert is a well know authority on COM (particularly in the scripting arena).

However, [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237580.aspx) has this to say:

> A BSTR with no data elements is either an empty BSTR or a NULL BSTR. An empty BSTR indicates a present, but zero-length, data value. A NULL BSTR indicates a data value that is not present.

So, officially they are both `BSTR`s with no data elements, but with slightly different semantics (though there's nothing to say that those 2 cases need to be handled differently in your application). In this case, I'd certainly follow Lippert's advice of treating them identically. For me, his real-world experience with how actual implementations work carries more weight than the one sentence in the official BSTR doc.

Comment: I was not the architect for VBScript, either de jure or de facto; I was a developer on the scripting team and implemented many features in VBScript, but I was certainly not at the architect level.

Comment: Eric - I removed that bit. Sorry about the mistake (I hope you take it as a compliment).

Answer (score 5):

Michael Burr gives what I think should be the accepted answer. It's unfortunate that the page for [`BSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx) in MSDN doesn't document this practice.

In addition, you can infer this behavior from these pages in the MSDN documentation:

- [`SysFreeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221481.aspx) page reports that if `bstr` is `null` the function simply returns.
- [`SysStringLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221240.aspx) page reports that passing a `null` for the `bstr` parameter returns zero for the string length.
- [`SysStringByteLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221097.aspx) page reports the same behavior; `null` means zero length.

However, the documentation is not complete:

- [`SysReAllocString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220986.aspx) does not mention what will happen if `*pbstr` is `null`.
- [`SysReAllocStringLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221533.aspx) does not mention what will happen if `*pbstr` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Handling null BSTR as an empty string seams to be a common practice, but the technical documentation found at Microsoft actually states that there **is** a difference between those two.

> For any document referencing both [MS-DTYP] and [MS-OAUT], specifying
>   BSTR in a wire representation context MUST be considered as a
>   reference to the transmitted BSTR type, while specifying BSTR in a
>   memory representation context MUST be considered as a reference to the
>   presented BSTR type ([MS-DTYP] section 2.2.5). Reflecting the
>   terminology used for presented BSTRs, a NULL BSTR, or NULL transmitted
>   BSTR, is defined as the wire representation of a NULL presented BSTR;
>   and an empty BSTR, or empty transmitted BSTR, is defined as the wire
>   representation of a zero-length presented BSTR. **Preserving this
>   distinction in the wire representation enables clients and servers to
>   distinguish between NULL presented BSTRs and zero-length presented
>   BSTRs, and thus associate possibly different, application-specific
>   semantics to these two values.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237580.aspx

So it's up to the implementations whether they handle both equal or not.